# The code signature version is no longer supported after adding Notification Service Extension Xcode 13.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, rich-notifications

We are trying to add notification service extension target to our existing project.
We are getting below error while building the app in real device.

Step :-
Added Notification service extension target to the project and when we build the app it successfully builds but unable to install the app in real device with error "code signature version is no longer supported."

**Error After Successful Build**
Unable to install "MyApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375

```
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-05-13 08:33:41 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116d1d614 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 272
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116d56dd8 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 160
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105ce1e58 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000116d56b30 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1336
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000124a41590 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 2916
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105e09194 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105e0a2ac __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 364
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b9888f60 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b988acac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b9892430 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b9892fa4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001b989d808 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b9a455b0 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b9a442c4 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
```

This is only happening when we are trying to add Notification service extension to existing application.
When we are trying to add Notification service extension in new application it is working properly.